# Converting mesh(not sure is it mesh) into object

Tags: mesh, objects, conversion

I want to convert that highlighted green triangle "Torus.001" , which represents icing in my case, into object so I can hide it and work with Donut.002.
First of all, is this icon representing a mesh or what? And how can I do it. I parented it to the donut like in Blender Guru tutorial on YT and kept transform, but he got this green triangle and object, and I got only this green triangle.
[image]

Comment: The green triangles are the mesh datas of the objects, not children objects. So the Torus.001 contains the 3d model of the Donut. Donut.002 is a child object, may be you looked for that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. And how can I hide this mesh data, so I can edit donut without icing in my way?

Comment: You can hide in Edit mode too with "h" and unhide with "alt+h". Or you can separate the selected parts (move to a new object) by pressing "p" and choose "By Selection".

Comment: Thanks, now it is lot clearer!